# lineair predictors on test observation - logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I want to do an Inverse Mill Ratio correction in my CLV prediction. Therefore, I conduct first a logistic regression to predict churn.

```
performLogisticRegression <- function(trainData, trainY, testData) {   
model <- glm(trainY~., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = trainData)  
LRpredictions <- predict(model,newdata=testData,type='response')   
return(list(model, LRpredictions)) }

LR <- performLogisticRegression(trainBIG, y_trainBIG_churn, test) 
LRmodel <- LR[[1]] 
summary(LRmodel) 
LRpredictions <- LR[[2]]
```

Thereafter, I calculate the IMR values for my train set:

```
IMR_train <- dnorm(LRmodel$linear.predictors)/pnorm(LRmodel$linear.predictors)
```

But now I am stuck, how do I get the linear.predictors for my test set? I only have the LRpredictions that are outputted as logits.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

instead of using prediction type "response", you should use "link".

```
LRpredictions <- predict(model,newdata=testData,type='link')
```